# Why does this program result in an overflow?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char test = 0x80;
    printf("%c\n", test);  /* To remove the "unused" warning */
    return 0;
}
```

I understand that a character is guaranteed to be **one** byte. 0x80 is also one byte. So why then do I get the following error/warning?

> error: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Werror=overflow]

In my case it's an error because I'm treating warnings as errors.

0x80 is the minimum value for which this warning/error appears. If I change it to 0x7F, this compiles fine. I used [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/9G1SLT) with the 'C99 strict' option to compile the code. It reported using gcc-4.7.2.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `char` type is signed in your compiler, so even though it does have 8 bits of information it cannot store values greater than 127 (0x7f).

The header `<limits.h>` defines macros that let you determine the signedness and range limits for integral types, including `char`.

Comment: Oh man. I can't believe I forgot such a minute detail. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The variable test is defined as char which defaults to signed char. range of which is 0 ~ 127 (7 bits). The last bit is reserved for sign. Maybe the error is due to trying to print a character with negative value(0x80 = -128).

Try with unsigned char for test and check if you get same error.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, as pointed out by Jon, this indeed was the reason. Changing it to an `unsigned char` removed that warning/error.